# how to limit SQL projections in linq query in case of zero or one to one relation

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following linq query

```
from c in Calendars
from cr in c.Readers
let fullName = cr.Reader.AsThirdParty.LastName + " " + cr.Reader.AsThirdParty.FirstName
where c.Id == 23
select new {Login = cr.Reader.Login, FullName = fullName}
```

which is projected as

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Calendar_Id] AS [Calendar_Id], 
[Extent2].[Login] AS [Login], 
[Extent3].[LastName] + N' ' + [Extent4].[FirstName] AS [C1]
FROM    [dbo].[CalendarReaders] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[VIPUsers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Reader_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ThirdParties] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[AsThirdParty_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ThirdParties] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[AsThirdParty_Id] = [Extent4].[Id]
WHERE 23 = [Extent1].[Calendar_Id]
```

In this case Extent4 is useless.

I just can't imagine how to write the linq query to prevent Extent4.

thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from c in Calendars
from cr in c.Readers
let thirdParty = cr.Reader.AsThirdParty
where c.Id == 23
select new {
    Login = cr.Reader.Login
,   FullName = thirdParty.LastName + " " + thirdParty.FirstName
}
```

This may help, because it would eliminate two separate mentions of `cr.Reader.AsThirdParty` expression.